# Can I use multiple authentication providers in Azure API Management?

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

Can I able to use two authentication providers to authenticate the user?

e.g. I have an Azure Active Directory and also I have Identity implemented for other external authentication providers?

If yes, could anyone explain how I can able to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to confirm - you want to enable multiple authentication providers for your developer portal?

You can do this on the Identities tab in the Security menu on the Publisher Portal. The check boxes on this page allow multiple authentication types - you can select Azure Active Directory (Developer or Premium instances only), other providers (Facebook, Microsoft account etc.) or user name and password.

For a guide on setting up [AAD integration](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-aad/)